# Prevent subclassing an abstract class interface in C++

Tags: c++, interface, subclassing, restriction

I provide a SDK to my users, allowing them to write DLLs in C++ for expanding the software.

The SDK headers mostly contain interface class definitions. These class are of two types:

- Some that the user must subclass and implement
- Some that are wrappers to core classes, passed by the app to the DLL functions as pointers, which can then be used as arguments by the DLL code for calling core functions. These interfaces should not be subclassed by the user and passed to the core functions, as they expect a specific core subclass.

I write in the manual the interfaces that should not be subclassed, and only used through pointers on objects provided by the app. But at some places, it's too tempting to subclass them in the SDK if you do not read the manual.

Would it be possible to prevent subclassing some interfaces in the SDK headers?

Comment: [c++11 has a final keyword](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/final)

Comment: The core problem is that you *do* need to subclass in your own implementation. So basically, your implementation would have to see a different declaration than your callers. (e.g. `final`, or a private CTor). That's certainly possible on most implementations with a reinterpret_cast, but I would advise against since it would be an ugly hack with marginal benefits.

Comment: @peterchen You wouldn't need a `reinterpret_cast`; the different interface he sees can be a derived class, so `dynamic_cast` can do the job.

Comment: @JamesKanze: The interface would have to look different for the client vs. for the imlementation (client needs to see a `final`, implementation a non-final.) `dynamic_cast` can cast along a class hierarchy, but it can't cast the `final` away.

Comment: @peterchen But you don't need (or want) the `final`.  You just want a class which the client can't derive from.  Making the constructors private, and then declaring a `friend`, for example, can achieve this.

Answer (score 0):

As long as the client doesn't need to use the pointer for anything but
passing it back into your DLL, you can just use a forward declaration;
you can't derive from an incomplete type.  (When faced with a similar
case recently, I went whole hog, and designed a special wrapper type
based on `void*`.  There's a lot of casting in the interface code, but
there's no way the client can do much other than pass the value back to
me.)

If the classes in question implement an interface which the client must
also use, there are two solutions.  The first is to change this,
replacing each of the member functions with a free function which takes
a pointer to the type, and just provide a forward declaration.  The
second is to use something like:

```
class InternallyVisibleInterface;

class ClientVisibleInterface
{
private:
    virtual void doSomething() = 0;
    ClientVisibleInterface() = default;
    friend class InternallyVisibleInterface;
protected:      //  Or public, depending on whether the client should
                //  be able to delete instances or not.
    virtual ~ClientVisibleInterface() = default;
public:
    void something();
};
```

and in your DLL:

```
class InternallyVisibleInterface : public ClientVisibleInterface
{
protected:
    InternallyVisibleInterface() {}

    //  And anything else you need.  If there is only one class in
    //  your application which should derive from the interface,
    //  this is it.  If there are several, they should derive from
    //  this class, rather than ClientVisibleInterface, since this
    //  is the only class which can construct the
    //  ClientVisibleInterface base class.
};

void ClientVisibleInterface::something()
{
    assert( dynamic_cast<InternallyVisibleInterface*>( this ) != nullptr );
    doSomething();
}
```

This offers two levels of protection: first, although derivation
directly from `ClientVisibleInterface` is possible, it's impossible for
the resulting class to have a constructor, and so it cannot be
instantiated.  And secondly, if the client code does cheat somehow,
there will be a runtime error if he does so.

You probably don't need both protections; one or the other should
suffice.  The private constructor will result in a compile time error,
rather than a runtime one.  On the other hand, without it, you don't
even have to mention the name of `InternallyVisibleInterface` in the
distributed headers.

Answer (score 0):

As soon as a developper has a developpement environment, he can do almost anything, and you should not even try to control that.

IMHO the best you can do is to identify the limit between the core application and the extension DLLs and ensure that objects received from those DLLs **are** or correct class, and abort with a distinctive message if they are not.

Using RTTI and `typeid` is generally frowned upon because it is generally the sign of a bad OOP design : in *normal* use case, calling virtual method is enough to have proper code invoked. But I think it can safely be considered in your use case.